# How to set "ignoreNumbers" for checkstyle magic number

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

Checkstyle Magic Number settings in SonarQube 4.4
[image: Checkstyle Magic Number in Sonar Qube]

In the documentation above, it says that having a comma separated list eg: "1,2,3,4,5" for ignoreNumbers will work. However, when I try to list out the numbers in a comma separated fashion, it fails. The only way I have gotten it to work is setting ignoreNumbers as a single integer.

Comment: Looks like a SonarQube bug to me (not a Checkstyle bug). The rule definition says this parameter is an int array (`i{}`). It is the *only* int array anywhere in the Checkstyle plugin, so maybe int arrays are just not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that affects the Checkstyle plugin with SonarQube 4.4+ versions.

Feel free to watch and vote for it: [SONARCHKST-5](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCHKST-5)